# does `radix_tree_insert` need `spin_lock` to protect it

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, locking, spinlock, radix-tree

`radix_tree_insert` is protected by `spin_lock` in Linux kernel source code. But the dmesg shows warning information as below:

```
[  667.551326] dump_backtrace.cfi_jt+0x0/0x8
[  667.556266] show_stack+0x1c/0x2c
[  667.560415] dump_stack_lvl+0x94/0x100
[  667.565017] ___might_sleep+0x194/0x1e4
[  667.569688] __might_sleep+0x58/0x94
[  667.574112] slab_pre_alloc_hook+0x5c/0xf0
[  667.579066] kmem_cache_alloc+0x84/0x398
[  667.583830] radix_tree_node_alloc+0x74/0x138
[  667.589035] radix_tree_insert+0xf4/0x1fc
```

The warning information means `radix_tree_insert` might sleep, and it should not be in atomic context.
I also notice `radix_tree_insert` is not protected by `spin_lock` in some code.

Does radix_tree_insert need to be protected by spin_lock?
Do we need to care about the warning information?

Comment: Note the issue with calling it from interrupt level if it is already locked.

Comment: The code exhibiting the problem probably needs to call `radix_tree_preload` (or get a non-error return value from a call to `radix_tree_maybe_preload`) before acquiring the spin lock.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other function, which **modifies** a radix tree, `radix_tree_insert` should be called under those synchronization, which (at least) **prevents other modifications** to operate concurrently. This is clearly written in the header [include/linux/radix-tree.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/include/linux/radix-tree.h#L96) which declares the radix tree:

> - any function *modifying* the tree or tags (inserting or deleting
>   items, setting or clearing tags) must exclude other modifications, and
>   exclude any functions reading the tree.

Depending on a usage scenario for a **specific** radix tree, such synchronization could be spinlock, mutex or something else.

Normally, a synchronization mechanism for a specific radix tree is described near its declaration. E.g. the declaration in the `fs/btrfs/ctree.h` is following:

```
    /*
     * radix tree that keeps track of delayed nodes of every inode,
     * protected by inode_lock
     */
    struct radix_tree_root delayed_nodes_tree;
```

A type of synchronization for modifications should take into account gfp mask parameter, which is passed to the constructor of the radix tree and used for nodes allocation. That is, if this mask parameter is GFP_KERNEL, then modification operations shouldn't be called under a spinlock.